# Checkboxes affecting other forms

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox

I've thoroughly searched google and stackoverflow for an answer to this question, but I can't seem to figure this one out on my own.

I have a form on the bottom of every page of a website where users can subscribe to a newsletter. There are multiple newsletter options so the form has a checkbox. On the same page I have a pop-up that also invites users to subscribe to the newsletter. It is an identical form that is connected to the same mailing list. (The parameters must be the same for it to connect to the same mailing list)

The checkboxes work great on the form in the footer, but problems arise when trying to click on the popup checkboxes. When I click on the pop-up checkbox it checks it's sister checkbox in the footer, but it remains unchecked. This could just be a visual issue, but I need to get it fixed either way.

Here is the code: (It's a mailchimp form)

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://myaction" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Email Address" required>
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group input-group">
<div class="explain"><strong>Send me information about:</strong></div>
<div class="options"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[88888888][1]" id="mce-group[88888888]-88888888-0" class="css-checkbox"><label for="mce-group[88888888]-88888888-0" class="css-label side">Arizona</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[88888888][2]" id="mce-group[88888888]-88888888-1" class="css-checkbox"><label for="mce-group[88888888]-88888888-1" class="css-label side">Nevada</label></div>
<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="216818354ab65ad5465ad554ad585" value=""></div>
</form>
</div>
```

I have tried renaming the css classes to see if that would solve the problem, but the behavior is still present. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you post some code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes - Added example and code. Thanks! :)

Comment: Make sure they have unique name and ID

Comment: Can they have a unique name and ID while still submitting to the same list on mailchimp? The name and ID are assigned by mailchimp. I thought this might be the problem. If anyone has a way around that issue I would love to try it.

Comment: In case anyone is interested... in the confines of the mailchimp sign-up form, I will likely need to put one of the two forms in an iframe to avoid the 2 forms on 1 page problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was that my forms did not have unique names & IDs. Of course, with mailchimp forms this is a problem, because you have no control over the name & ID of a simple HTML mailchimp form. Under normal circumstances if you are using a simple html mailchimp form you cannot have 2 forms on one page.

However, if you put your form in an iframe you can get around this. Your browser loads it as a completely unique form and the same name / ID problem is avoided.

**Summary**

If you want to use multiple mailchimp forms on the same page (even in a pop-up) include them in iframes to avoid problems.